# express-validator/node-validator: how to validate that property exists, and should be present

Tags: node.js, express

is there a validation like:

```
req.checkBody('property', 'should be present').isPresent();
```

The value itself, does not matter.

for now i use this solution:
`.isLength()`

**update**
- `.isLength()` is a bad solution, because it tests if the value is a string.
- and you can not send POST value as 'undefined' from your browser, because of JSON.stringify method, that ignores such properties.
So the validation against `!== undefined` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the [express validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) module?

If yes, is this something that works for you?

```
req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty()
```

***UPDATE***

According to the documentation does not exist the validator that you want. Creating your custom one can be the solution:

```
expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    isPresent: function(value) {
        return (typeof value !== 'undefined');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: yes i use the validator, but the value could be empty.. the property should be only present, with any value.

Comment: @ya_dimon do you accept only strings or can be numbers and booleans as well?

Comment: any value, but restriction to strings could be ok too.

Comment: can you please update the answer again, with isDefined, or better isPresent/isExists, because i m looking for such validation

Comment: pls fix the comparison to `!==`